# Finding the maximum tuple in a vector

Tags: c++, stl

My vector contains three tuples, and I want to find the tuple whose third element is largest. Here's my code:

```
std::vector<std::tuple<int, double, double>> v;
v.push_back(std::make_tuple(0, 5.0, 7.0));
v.push_back(std::make_tuple(1, 8.5, 4.5));
v.push_back(std::make_tuple(2, 11.2, 3.8));

std::tuple<int, double, double> result;
result = std::max(v.begin(), v.end(),
[]( const std::tuple<int, double, double>& x, 
    const std::tuple<int, double, double>& y ) { 
    return std::get<2>(x) > std::get<2>(y); });
```

g++ gives me a lengthy error: `no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::tuple<int, double, double>*, std::vector<std::tuple<int, double, double> > >’ to ‘const std::tuple<int, double, double>&’`

I've made all the changes I can think of, but nothing works. Any thoughts?

Comment: Wrong function. You want `std::max_element`. `std::max` passes iterators to the lambda, and not values. Or, you can just change your lambda to take a pair of iterators. P.S. If you read the error message it tells you exactly what's happening. Although C++ has a reputation for confusing error messages, on balance this one is pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace `std::max` with `std::max_element` like that.

```
std::vector<std::tuple<int, double, double>> v;
v.emplace_back(0, 5.0, 7.0);
v.emplace_back(1, 8.5, 4.5);
v.emplace_back(2, 11.2, 3.8);

auto result = std::max_element(v.begin(), v.end(),
                               [](const std::tuple<int, double, double> &x,
                                  const std::tuple<int, double, double> &y) {
                                   return std::get<2>(x) < std::get<2>(y);
                               });
```

Comment: Note that `std::max_element` returns an **iterator**, not a value. The iterator must be dereferenced to obtain the tuple value.

Comment: Comparison must also change, your currently return min element.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing iterators to [`std::max()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max). Therefore, it, in turn, passes iterators to the lambda, not the values (i.e., not the tuples, but iterators to the tuples).

To obtain the maximum value in an iterator range, you can use the [`std::max_element`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element) function template. What the *maximum* will be, depends on the comparison function object that is passed to `std::max_element`:

> Comparison function object (i.e. an object that satisfies the requirements of `Compare`) which **returns true if the first argument is *less* than the second**.

So, you can use the following lambda expression for performing the comparison:

```
auto cmp = [](const auto& a, const auto& b) {
              return std::get<2>(a) < std::get<2>(b);
};
```

Then, just pass the `cmp` above to `std::max_element()`:

```
auto max_it = std::max_element(v.begin(), v.end(), cmp);
auto max = *max_it; // max_it may be v.end()!!!
```

Note that `std::max_element` doesn't return the maximum value, but an iterator to it. If the passed iterator pair corresponds to an empty range (e.g., if the vector is empty), then the returned iterator will be `v.end()`.

Answer (score 0):

I add my flavor to what @2power10 answered:

```
auto result = std::max_element(v.begin(), v.end(),
                               [](const auto &x, const auto &y) {
                                 return std::get<2>(x) > std::get<2>(y);
                              });
```

Comment: and same issue with comparer order.